# add specific class to hide button play video

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css

I have two pages in my website who has video content, I already hide play video button my first page with my code :

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
 display:none !important;
}
```

but I don't want my second page hide play video button , So I need add class to my first page so that my second page still show play video button. Help me please

Comment: Add class to body of page you want it to be hidden,  and then use: `.bodyClass video::-webkit-media-controls {
 display:none !important;
}`. Or just set class to video tag. Honestly, i don't really understand what is your issue/question?!....  If you don't know how to add class, then you have to provide more context to your question, this is really too broad

Comment: is there any solution without add class in my body of page? maybe add class in <div> before video?

Comment: Of course you can do whatever you want BUT what is your issue???